# Pruning least-close matches in affinity propagation clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm working on clustering a list of similar company names (e.g. returning 'Google Inc.' as the exemplar for 'Google Switzerland AG', 'Google Ventures Ltd.', 'Google France SA', etc.), and have settled on affinity propagation with Jaccard similarity as the pairwise similarity metric, which is providing good results so far.

The issue, though, is that affinity propagation returns "comprehensive" (not sure if this is the right term) clusters; every data point is associated with an exemplar. This results in some not-so-close matches being associated with an exemplar (e.g. even if "Apple" is not close to any other company names, "Apple" will still correspond to an exemplar.

Visually, what I'd like to accomplish is analogous to excluding the furthest data points in this example:

[image: enter link description here]

What would be the best way of doing this? Should I re-run the Jaccard similarities within each exemplar/examples set and exclude poor matches?